# inline If run all part of statements with out condition

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a method to get all Ticket with filtering by `FromDate` .
my code like this :

```
public List<Model.Ticket> SelectList(DateTime? fromDate = null)
{
    db.Tickets.Where(row=> (!fromDate.HasValue || (fromDate.HasValue ? (row.Date.Date >= fromDate.Value.Date) : false));
}
```

but when pass null  It returns an exception :

> Nullable object must have a value.

what's wrong?

Comment: when debug it , fromDate is `null`

Comment: This is not a good duplicate of the "what is a null reference exception" because if you look at the expression the OP has already handled the case where `fromDate == null`, yet clearly this crashes. So this is not "you need to find the part that is null", this is more "why does Entity Framework (or Linq2Sql) behave like this.

Comment: Is this LINQ to EF, LINQ to SQL or LINQ to something else? (If something else, what?) It matters, because the different LINQ providers might handle the expression tree generated by your where clause differently. Also, are there any other nullable instances involved here - could `db` or `row.Date` be `null`?

Comment: @TomasLycken its Linq to SQL , and `row.Date` is `not null`

Comment: As Nithila Shanmugananthan notes in their answer, the syntax above is still incomplete; I guess you're missing `row => ` at the beginning of the argument to `.Where(...)`...? Could you update the question to list the exact code you're using? (copy using ctrl-c, ctrl-v, not by re-writing it here!)

Comment: @TomasLycken yes , updated

Comment: @Have you run this code using the debugger? What do you see then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all Ticket with filtering by FromDate, But in your where condition will only return true or false acording to the formdate you are passing as a parameter.But where condition expect a logic to filter data from the table acording to.You have to modify your where condition as

```
where(ticket=>ticket.formDate--here what ever the condition you need to apply)
```

NB: For your lambda expression( 
 `db.Tickets.Where(!fromDate.HasValue || (fromDate.HasValue ? (row.Date.Date >= fromDate.Value.Date) : false))`
)
the db query will be

```
 select * from Tickets where true/false--acording to the output
```

this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your object declaration you have to initialize it

Answer (score 0):

Null to be initialized by using `new` keyword. As directly assigning null to certain object doesn't carry desired contents. Debugging still shows value to `null` but it can't be instantiated likewise.

Comment: whats your idea to do this ?

Comment: Just have a try using `new` keyword where you declaring your problematic object